# Use vogels js to implement pagination

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am implementing a website with a dynamodb + nodejs backend. I use Vogels.js in server side to query dynamodb and show results on a webpage. Because my query returns a lot of results, I would like to return only N (such as 5) results back to a user initially, and return the next N results when the user asks for more.

Is there a way I can run two vogels queries with the second query starts from the place where the first query left off ? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, vogels fully supports pagination on both query and scan operations.

For example:

```
var Tweet = vogels.define('tweet', {
  hashKey  : 'UserId',
  rangeKey : 'PublishedDateTime',
  schema : {
    UserId            : Joi.string(),
    PublishedDateTime : Joi.date().default(Date.now),
    content           : Joi.string()
  }
});

// Fetch the 5 most recent tweets from user with id 555:
Tweet.query(555).limit(5).descending().exec(function (err, data) {
  var paginationKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;

  // Fetch the next page of 5 tweets
  Tweet.query(555).limit(5).descending().startKey(paginationKey).exec()
});
```

Comment: this is great for `next` page in pagination. Is there any out of the box solution for `previous` page?

Comment: What do mean with 'LastEvaluatedKey' ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, DynamoDB has some thing called "LastEvaluatedKey" which will server your purpose.

**Step 1)** Query your table with option "Limit" = number of records

refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

**Step 2)** If your query has more records than the "Limit value", DynamoDB will return a "LastEvaluatedKey" which you can pass in your next query as "ExclusiveStartKey" to get next set of records until there are no records left

refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query

**Note:**  Be aware that to get previous set of records you might have to store all the "LastEvaluatedKeys" and  implement this at application level

Comment: Thank you for the reply ! I am using Vogels JS to access dynamoDB instead of Amazon DynamoDB JS API, and am wondering how to do it in Vogels.

Comment: I am guessing you are using this https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels, it is just a mapper and all the option that I had mention is present in it.

Comment: Yes. I am using github.com/ryanfitz/vogels. I did not find how to specify LastEvaluatedKey in vogels' document. Will dig into the code to see how it work. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Found it. Query.prototype.startKey() is the method to pass LastEvaluatedKey in the next query.